# Why was Moshe told to put two cabbages on top of the Aron?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Shmot 25:19](http://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.25.19?lang=he):

> ועשה כרוב אחד מקצה מזה וכרוב אחד מקצה מזה
>
> And make one cabbage on this side and one cabbage on this side

What purpose do the 2 cabbages have doing on top of the ark? Wouldn't they eventually become sour kraut and pickle the aron?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

Those are [Krauts](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraut). As Indiana Jones can attest, you have to get past Krauts to get to the Ark of the Covenant.