# PTIJ: How did the cabbages get their wings?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Follow up to a [previous PTIJ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56068/5275) question that I asked about why the Aron (ark) had cabbages on top of it.

[Shemot 25:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=420&hilite=) says that the cabbages should spread their wings upwards to cover the ark curtain. How did the cabbages get their wings?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

From this recipe:

http://www.taste.com.au/recipes/spicy-wings-asian-coleslaw/129608f9-c97e-448e-b4a6-da06f2c51b73

Therefore, the wings aren't really cabbage wings, but chicken wings.

However, this will have to do with the Machlokes of whether or not one can one can use animals as a Sechach (whether they are considered Gidulei Karka), see [Rashi Sukkah 11b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.11b.16?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en).  This is necessary because it says:

> **סוככ**ים בכנפיהם על הכפורת

Comment: Hot wingeddy wing! I was just looking at a similar recipe and was about to post it as my own answer. As for covering, I think the sauce can be used for schach.

Comment: @DanF good idea for Schach.  But only if it's congealed, as we see at the top of the next Amud (Yayin Karush Haba Misnir)... https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.12a.4?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en